# How to fix "line:1: error: syntax error!"

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm trying to write a parser using flex and bison.However, no matter how I modify the files, the error "syntax error in line 1" always appears.
This is the test.vm file of yyinput:

```
$asfdfsdf
sdfsdfs
sdfsdfsd
sdfsdfsd
sfsdfd
```

this is the vtl4.l file:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "context.h"
#include "bool.h"
#include "vtl4.tab.h"
%}
%%
(.|\n)* {yylval.string = yytext;return CONTENT;}
<<EOF>> {return FINAL;}
%%
```

This is the vtl4.y file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bool.h"
#include "parser.h"
#include "context.h"
#include "vtl4.tab.h"

extern FILE * yyin;
extern FILE * yyout;
extern int yylex();
extern int yywrap();
%}

%union {
struct simpleNode *ast;
double d;
int i;
bool b;
char* string;
struct symbol *sym;
}

%type <ast> root stmts stmt

%token <string> CONTENT

%token FINAL

%%

root:stmts FINAL {printf("root\n");$$ = process($1);traverse($$);}
;

stmts: {printf("stmts:stmt\n");$$ = 0;}
|stmts stmt {printf("stmts:stmts stmt\n");$$ = add_ybrother($1,$2);}
;

stmt:CONTENT {printf("stmt\n");$$ = text($1);}
;

%%
int main(){
FILE *src;
src = fopen("test.vm","r");
yyin = src;
yyparse();
fclose(src);
return 1;
}

int yywrap(){
return 1;
}
```

Makefile:

```
CC=cc

FLEX=vtl4.l

BISON=vtl4.y

parse:vtl4.tab.c lex.yy.c
       $(CC) -o out *.c -ll


vtl4.tab.c:$(BISON)
      bison -d $(BISON) --report=all

lex.yy.c:$(FLEX)
        flex $(FLEX)
```

when I run ./out ,it will print the right result,but always says "line:1: error: syntax error" at last!I don't know why?

It works well when I edit the lex rule

```
<<EOF>> {return FINAL;}
```

to

```
<<EOF>> {yyterminate();}
```

and modify the yacc rule

```
root:stmts FINAL {printf("root\n");$$ = process($1);traverse($$);}
```

to

```
root:stmts {printf("root\n");$$ = process($1);traverse($$);}
```

but I don't know why?

Answer (score 2):

By using the `return FINAL` in the `<<EOF>>` rule the tokenizer will keep returning `FINAL` on an end-of-file. When `flex` is used in combination with `bison` you don't have to (and should not) make use of an explicit end-of-file token. Just rely on the 0 that will be returned by `yylex` on end-of-file, provided `yywrap` returns 1. This is exactly what `yyterminate` does for you too and that is why that works fine.

In this case the grammar is confronted with an endless stream of `FINAL` tokens that it can't handle. Of course you should not accommodate this endless stream in your grammar because the grammar will then be 'correct' but will never terminate.

I assume you are aware your tokenizer will match a complete file in a single `CONTENT` token, so even though your grammar supports a list of `CONTENT` tokens it will always see only one.

P.S: I found the problem by using the `-t` option to `bison` which adds a debug trace to the parsers and it showed that it choked on the second occurrence of `FINAL`.

P.S2: In the `Makefile` you used `*.c` in the compiler invocation for `parse`. This is quite dangerous as some random `.c` files may hang out in your directory. Better use `$^` to refer to all files the rule depends on.

P.S3: As you have defined your own `yywrap` and `main` you can lose the `-ll`.